# How do I view the RDS_ prefixed environment variables in AWS ElasticBeanstalk?

Tags: amazon-ebs, environment-variables, amazon-rds

If you set up RDS with ElasticBeanstalk how can you go into the box (via  `eb ssh`) and view the environment variables that are set when you apply RDS to your EB Instance?

Amazon automatically sets up these environment variables.

- `RDS_DB_NAME`
- `RDS_USERNAME`
- `RDS_PASSWORD`
- `RDS_HOSTNAME`
- `RDS_PORT`

It seems that you can only view in the process that runs your application.

I'd like to view these via the terminal some way, the `eb printenv` command does not show them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to do it.

First `ssh` into the eb instance.

```
eb ssh
```

Then un the following command

```
sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment --output YAML
```

Alternatively `--output YAML` can be `--output json`.

Or if you want you can pipe the variables into a node command like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var strings = []
process.stdin.resume()
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8')
process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
  var json = JSON.parse(data)
  for (var key in json) {
    var val = json[key]
    strings.push(key + '="' + val + '"')
  }
})
process.stdin.on('end', function() {
  var output = strings.join('\n')
  process.stdout.write(output)
})
```

And use `source` to have `.ebextension` scripts get access to the env variables.

Answer (score 3):

Just Simple.

You should go to environment configurations of the current application being running over your elastic beanstalk.

First ssh into the elastic beanstalk instance like the above answer.

`ssh eb`

If you wanna show the environment variables related to RDS (like `RDS_DB_NAME`), then

`cat /opt/python/current/env`

You will also see some variables of `aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment` in `option_settings` together,  typed before.

Additionally, if you want to apply that environment variables,

`source /opt/python/current/env`

And you can see those variables by scripting `env`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version that adds the vars to the current session

`sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment --output yaml | sed -n '1!p' | sed -e 's/^\(.*\): /\1=/g' | sed -e 's/^/export /' > env.sh; source env.sh`

It drops a temp file, but it works.